# Keep only the unique rows whose sum in another column is more than 1000 (Python Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas df like this:

```
c1 | c2 | c3 | Impressions
_________________________________________
a  | a  | a  | 1200
a  | a  | a  | 2000
b  | c  | c  | 1001
b  | c  | z  | 4000
c  | c  | z  | 50
c  | c  | z  | 40
```

I want to group all the row by c1, c2, c3 and sum the impressions. If the sum is less than 1000, I want to drop the rows. Final output should be:

```
c1 | c2 | c3 | Impressions
_________________________________________
a  | a  | a  | 3200
b  | c  | c  | 1001
b  | c  | z  | 4000
```

I was trying to use groupby and sum, then try to revert to the original form, but I think it's not effective.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['c1','c2','c3']).sum()
new_df = new_df[new_df['Impressions'] > 1000]
```

Comment: That's  what i've already tried, but how can i revert to the ungrouped dataframe? Also, is this the best option? I have a huge df and it's kinda slow

Comment: You cannot reverse the procedure. You now have two DFs. What do you want to do next?

Comment: you could do `df.loc[df.groupby(['c1','c2','c3'])['Impressions'].transform('sum') >= 1000]`